# json_decode not interpreting array

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, json

I have a following JSON string, arriving via AJAX to server:

```
{"Names":"[{0:'asdasd'}]","Values":"[{0:'ad'}]"}
```

As you see, Names and Values were intended to hold an array. Problem is, when I call 
`$data = json_decode(stripslashes($_POST['data']), true);
$data['Names'][0]` I don't get 'asdasd' as I wanted, but `"["` symbol. Where the problem lies?

**P.S.** JS code, sending JSON string:

```
            var arr_names = "[";
        names.each(function(i){
            arr_names += "{" + i + ":'" + $(this).val() + "'}";
            if (i < names.length-1) arr_names += ",";
        });
        arr_names += "]";

        var arr_val = "[";
        values.each(function(i){
            arr_val += "{" + i + ":'" + $(this).val() + "'}";
            if (i < values.length-1) arr_val += ",";
        });
        arr_val += "]";

        var el = { "Names" : arr_names, "Values" : arr_val };
        el = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(el));

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            dataType:"html",
            data:"m=1&t="+type+"&data="+el,
            url:plugin_path+"option-proc.php",
            success: function(rsp){
                $("#result").html(rsp);
            }
        });
```

names and values are a bunch of text fields, selected by the class.
**m** and **t** variables being sent, are completely irrelevant to the case :)

Comment: That JSON is not really correct. The arrays should probably not be encoded as strings like that, because it'll force you to have to do multiple decode passes.

Comment: Could you give a link to some best practices guides?

Comment: Best practises: 1. Write JSON, not JavaScript. 2. Encode your data using JSON. Don't serialise things JSON has built into strings first.

Comment: *1. Write JSON, not JavaScript.* - what do you mean by it? I need to build a JSON string. Dynamically.

Comment: Your JSON should look like: `{"Names": [{"0":"asdasd"}] ,"Values":[{"0":"ad"}]}` - no quotes around the arrays, all property names must be quoted, and all quotes must be " and not ' quotes.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take it in account.

Comment: I'm wondering if the form you're creating is really what you're after (I don't understand the `0`-keyed object). Is this what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/UATZ8/ (And if you need multiple values: http://jsfiddle.net/UATZ8/1/) (Note, you'll need to have Chrome or Firebug console open.)

Comment: Why don't you use `JSON.stringify` to create the JSON? Creating  it manually is bad.

Comment: Is it a correct JSON, that starts from "["? I need a JSON string, not an object.

Comment: @FelixKling if you'd look through my code, you could see that I am using JSON.stringify

Comment: What do you propose? I need some sort of **dynamically** created object, which later is serialized into JSON string. Suggestions?

Comment: Then create the object properly and serialize it. E.g. `var json = JSON.stringify({Names: names.map(function() { return $(this).val();}).get(), Values: values.map(function() { return $(this).val();}).get()});`

Comment: All I'm saying is that it looks as if the index in `names` relates to the corresponding index in `values`. If that's the case, you don't need two objects; make an array of objects and set `name` equal to the `value`, then `.stringify()` the array like so: http://jsfiddle.net/UATZ8/2/

Comment: @FelixKling
Well, okay, your method seems more robust. Thanks for your input.

Comment: @JaredFarrish yeah, that's certainly better.

Answer (score 2):

The string is encoded incorrectly. $data['Names'] is a string, so by accessing [0] you'll get the first character.

If you also json_decode $data['Names'] again you should get something working, although also that is actually incorrectly ecoded (as an object with numeric indexes rather than an array.) I'm pretty sure strict json parsers will fail on that inner-string.

I'd suggest fixing whatever generates it, rather than on the decoding side.